# Error al correr avdmanager desde linea de comandos

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, zsh

He instalado Cordova en mi ordenador (Mac) y me estoy encontrando con un problema a la hora de configurar android. Estoy siguiendo los [pasos de este tutorial](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html):

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld

cd hello

cordova platform add android
cordova platform add ios

cordova platform ls
```

Hasta aquí todo bien. Entonces ejecuto el siguiente paso:

```
cordova requirements
```

Y ahí es donde recibo el siguiente error:

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 17.0.1
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed 
Command failed with exit code 1: avdmanager list target
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 5 more
Gradle: installed /usr/local/Cellar/gradle/8.0.2/bin/gradle

Requirements check results for ios:
Apple macOS: installed darwin
Xcode: installed 14.2
ios-deploy: installed 1.11.4
CocoaPods: installed 1.12.1
Some of requirements check failed
```

Mirando en Internet, encontré diferentes opciones que he ido probando:

- Actualicé mi fichero `.zshrc` para que los valores correctos se exportaran en el PATH y cambie de `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` a `ANDROID_HOME`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/mi/path/a/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$PATH:/mi/path/a/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/
export PATH=$PATH:/mi/path/a/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/
export ANDROID_HOME=/mi/path/a/android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:/mi/path/a/android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:/mi/path/a/android/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/mi/path/a/android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/mi/path/a/android/sdk/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:/mi/path/a/android/sdk/build-tools
```

- Reinstalé Android Studio a la última versión (ahora tengo Giraffe). Y por asegurarme, lo desinstalé completamente y volví a instalar desde cero.
- Dentro de Android Studio, fui a la configuración y actualicé todas las SDK Tools con las últimas versiones (latest). Y de nuevo para asegurarme, las desinstalé todas, reinicié y volví a instalarlas desde cero.
- Bajé la versión de Java a 11 (en algunas publicaciones se recomendaba incluso más bajo a 8, pero entonces tendría otros problemas). Acabé bajando las versiones de Gradle (de 8 a 7), Java (17 a 11), y Gradle (8 a 7), pero nada, como se indica en [la documentación](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#requirements-and-support). El problema sigue apareciendo:

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 11.0.20
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed 
Command failed with exit code 1: avdmanager list target
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 5 more
Gradle: installed /usr/local/Cellar/gradle@7/7.6.2/bin/gradle

Requirements check results for ios:
Apple macOS: installed darwin
Xcode: installed 14.2
ios-deploy: installed 1.11.4
CocoaPods: installed 1.12.1
Some of requirements check failed
```

No es un problema con Cordova: si ejecuto el comando `cordova build android`, la aplicación compila y se hace build sin problemas. Parece un problema con mi instalación de android (lo instalé hace años y sólo recientemente he vuelto a probar).

Quizás sea un problema con incompatibilidad de versiones pero no termino de ver donde está la raíz, porque todas las versiones son correctas cuando corro el comando `cordova requirements`. Pero aún así, el *android target* falla. Aunque si voy a Android Studio puede ver que hay máquinas creadas. ¿Por qué puede ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la causa del problema: la nueva instalación de Cordova y Android era correcta (incluso las versiones), pero los comandos de android que se estaban ejecutando eran antiguos y eso es lo que creaba el fallo. Como el error salía al ejecutar `avdmanager` o `sdkmanager`, hice un `which` de ambos:

```
which avdmanager
which sdkmanager
```

En ambos casos, el resultado era `/usr/local/bin`. Había una instalación previa de android que tenía los comandos en `/usr/local/bin` (debe ser la instalación que hice hace unos años porque los ficheros tienen fecha de 2020) y como esa ruta estaba al principio del PATH, se usaban esos comandos viejos en lugar de los nuevos que acababa de instalar.

Tengo que ver como desinstalar los comandos obsoletos de android (si no recuerdo mal hice la instalación con brew), pero como una solución rápida, lo que hice fue poner los directorios con la nueva instalación al principio del PATH en vez de al final. El problema se solucionó cambiando unas líneas en el archivo `.zshrc` del home:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/mi/path/a/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$PATH:/mi/path/a/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/
export PATH=$PATH:/mi/path/a/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/
export ANDROID_HOME=/mi/path/a/android/sdk
export PATH=/mi/path/a/android/sdk:$PATH
export PATH=/mi/path/a/android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=/mi/path/a/android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/mi/path/a/android/sdk/emulator:$PATH
export PATH=/mi/path/a/android/sdk/build-tools:$PATH
```

Nota como los últimos 5 exports concatenan el `$PATH` al final en vez de al principio. Aunque esta solución funciona, no es ideal porque sigue habiendo *basura* en mi ordenador: tengo dos versiones de android SDK. Tengo que ver cómo eliminar la versión obsoleta.

Comment: La versión de Java a usar esta relacionada a la versión de Android Studio y a su vez a la versión de Gradle y su plugin usado. Para eliminar el Android SDK "obsoleto" simplemente se elimina su directorio, probablemente tendrás algunas rutas que hacian referencia a este SDK.

Comment: @Jorgesys al final los borré usando `brew uninstall --cask android-sdk`.